# Preprocessing numbers in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

While preprocessing data I will get a same numerical features with different formats.
For example:

```
1x4 wire       1 x 4 wire
1-1/2x1 wire   1-1/2 x 1 wire
11/2x1 wire    1-1/2 x 1 wire
```

I need to standardize different formats to one single format .

One approch we thought is to remove x, -, / and space and combine everything.
i.e :

```
1x4 wire       1 x 4 wire         14 wire
1-1/2x1 wire   1-1/2 x 1 wire     1121 wire
11/2x1 wire    1-1/2 x 1 wire     1121 wire
```

Can anyone tell how to implement the above approach in Python ?

I tried the following code to match the desired pattern :

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(\d+.*?)\s?')
```

I am not getting how to use its output to `re.sub`.

Comment: 1. Learn Python. 2. Write code in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 2 ways to use `re.sub` to remove any character x, - or / , with the blank spaces located just before and just after, if it precedes and follows a numerical character:

```
import re

myText = """
            1-1/2x1 wire cross box
            1x4 wire       1 x 4 wire         14 wire
            1-1/2x1 wire   1-1/2 x 1 wire     1121 wire
            11/2x1 wire    1-1/2 x 1 wire     1121 wire
        """

# First way
myNewText1 =  re.sub(r'(?<=([0-9])) *[x\-\/] *(?=([0-9]))', '', myText)
print(myNewText1)

# Second way (by defining first a regex pattern)
myPattern = re.compile(r'(?<=([0-9])) *[x\-\/] *(?=([0-9]))')
myNewText2 =  myPattern.sub('', myText)
print(myNewText2)
```

Both print the following result:

```
1121 wire cross box
14 wire       14 wire         14 wire
1121 wire   1121 wire     1121 wire
1121 wire    1121 wire     1121 wire
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. if my input is `f="1-1/2x1 wire cross box"` then i will get `myNewText1 =  re.sub(r' *[x\-\/] *', '', f)`
`print(myNewText1)`
`1121 wire cross bo`. i need to remove only when it is with digits.
`